# Logging post data in TurboGears / Pylons

Tags: logging, pylons, turbogears2

Does TurboGears (2.1.5) or Pylons (1.0) provide a logger for printing form parameters (aka post data or post parameters) with each post / put request?  Something similar to Rails' default parameter logging:

> ```
> Started PUT "/customers/4/addresses/13" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-10 13:45:41 +0000
> Processing by AddressesController#update as HTML
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"foo",
>   "address"=>{"label"=>"shipping"},
>   "commit"=>"Update Address", "id"=>"13"}
> ```

I have loggers for `routes.middleware` and `pylons` enabled at `DEBUG` level, but neither prints the actual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by placing a logging command in `BaseController.__call__` and printing `tg.request.params`